# VScode formatter, keep open bracket at same line (PHP)

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I have enable the "editor.formatOnSave" setting but in php files when the code is formate, all the open brackets are going to a new line. i just want them to stay in the same line ex

```
function test{

}
```

not

```
function test
{

}
```

I am looking for a solution all day but i cant find anything

Comment: Are you using any plugins?

Comment: @Script47 no plugin that is related with the code format

Comment: Same problema here. Have you found any solution? I'm using PHP Intellisense.

Comment: @GuilhermeRamalho no, still nothing

Comment: What formatteer do you use? Do you have https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense installed?

Comment: @Ovsyanka yes i have

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The new versions of VScode include this feature already.

You just need to search for "intelephense" in the VScode settings, and look for a setting called "Braces".

[image: VScode Intelephense braces setting]

Comment: It's so nice! Easy switch!

Comment: this still doesn't work for me :-( ... I have VSCode 1.62.3 and I have changed the format of the braces to k&r, yet the brace still jumps to the next line when I make a class. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you figure it out Jon? I'm also getting the same issue...

Answer (score 69):

If you want to have your php code formatted like this

```php
function test {

}
```

then use [intelephense](https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense) with the following settings.

```json
  "intelephense.format.braces": "k&r"
```

### Edit

As @Pinonirvana said in his answer, you can now do this through the GUI.
You'll find this information under du user settings:

Short key -> `Ctrl+,`

or

File > Preferences > Settings

[image]

Comment: Can't believe how long it took me to get to this solution. Thanks so much!!!

Comment: Thanks for this, this option was introduced in vscode-intelephense in 2020 ( https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense/issues/730 ) and is simpler than Ovsyanka's solution so it should be the new accepted answer!

Comment: The screenshot at https://stackoverflow.com/a/66115402/470749 helped.

Comment: even slightly quicker: menu File > Preferences > Settings and type "intelephense format braces" in the "Search settings" input to get straight to the "Intelephense > Format: Braces" setting

Comment: You saved someone yay!

Answer (score 10):

There is default formatter in the [intelephence](https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense) and it doesen't have many options to customize. You can disable it in the php language-specific settings:

```
~/.config/Code - OSS/User/settings.json:
----------
...
"[php]": {
    // "editor.defaultFormatter": "bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client"
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "kokororin.vscode-phpfmt"
},
...
```

Then you can use some another formatter that support customization, [phpfmt](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kokororin.vscode-phpfmt) for example. Here is my settings:

```
"phpfmt.exclude": [
    "AllmanStyleBraces"
],
"phpfmt.smart_linebreak_after_curly": true,
"phpfmt.psr2": false,
"phpfmt.detect_indent": true
```

Comment: Great! Works even better after replacing "detect_indent" with     "phpfmt.indent_with_space": 4

Answer (score 5):

Easy Step, please follow below step -

1. [image]
2. [image]